# Setting up EventListeners across singular CSS class comes up null when used with multiple element types

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm trying to make floating labels dynamically resize themselves when you click on an input like more forms do today. I'm working with vanilla JS and exclusively going to use vanilla JS for this problem.

I have it set up currently so that it works with the  tag. However, for my  tag, it does not. For some reason, every time I've looked into this problem across a day or two or looking and then stepping away to reset myself, I cannot see why my  element comes up null when I try to add the .active class to it, so as to make the font and animation play properly. Here is the JS script as it functions right now

```
  
    // add active class
    const handleFocus = (e) => {
      const target = e.target;
      target.parentNode.classList.add('active');
      target.setAttribute('placeholder', target.getAttribute('data-placeholder'));
    };
    
    // remove active class
    const handleBlur = (e) => {
      const target = e.target;
      if(!target.value) {
        target.parentNode.classList.remove('active');
      }
      target.removeAttribute('placeholder');
    };
    
    // register events
    const bindEvents = (element) => {
      const floatField = element.querySelector('input');
      floatField.addEventListener('focus', handleFocus);
      floatField.addEventListener('blur', handleBlur);   
    };
    
    // get DOM elements
    const init = () => {
      const floatContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.float-container');
      //I can see the textarea element in this list.
      console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.float-container'));
      floatContainers.forEach((element) => {
        
        if (element.querySelector('input').value) {
          element.classList.add('active');
        }
        //The commented section below causes a "TypeError querySeclector is null"
        /*
        if (element.querySelector('textarea').value) {
          element.classList.add('active');
        }
        */
        bindEvents(element);
      });
    };
    
    return {
      init: init
    };
  })();
  
   window.onload=FloatLabel.init();
```

As mentioned in the commented part of the script, when I check the console.log for the list of elements it grabs, I can see the  in that list. However, when I try to add the active class for when checking if text is inside the textarea, it comes up null and breaks the script.

I'm not sure if there's something I'm not seeing, or if I fundamentally don't know/understand part of what's going on. I have also checked to make sure the TypeError I'm getting is not related to the DOM not being ready. I've also made sure that the script is at the bottom of the php file and and for good measure added the defer keyword too it. Though, from what I understand about JS, putting defer on a script that's at the bottom of the document doesn't do anything, but I digress. Here is the CSS classes involved.

```
{
    width: 66%;
    position: relative;
}

.float-container.small input
{
    width: 50%;
    outline-offset: 1px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 4px 10px 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.float-container.small textarea
{
    width: 100%;
    outline-offset: 1px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 4px 10px 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: red;
}

.float-container.large input 
{
    width: 100%;
    outline-offset: 1px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 4px 10px 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.float-container.active
{
    border: 2px solid #1A57FF;
    outline: 2px solid rgba(26, 87, 255, 0.3);
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.float-container.active label
{
    transform: translate(0, 4px) scale(.75);
}



.floating-text
{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
    transform: translate(0, 16px) scale(1);
    transform-origin: top left;
    transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Finally, here is the portion of the form from the document

```
<div id="floatContainer" class="float-container small">
                    <label for="fName" class="floating-text">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName" data-placeholder="First name"><br>
                </div>
                <p id="fName-validate" class="form-validate-text"><p>
                <div id="floatContainer" class="float-container small">
                    <label for="lName" class="floating-text">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName" data-placeholder="Last name"><br>    
                </div>
                <p id="lName-validate" class="form-validate-text"><p>
                <div id="floatContainer" class="float-container small">
                    <label for="email" class="floating-text">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" data-placeholder="Email"><br>
                </div>
                <p id="email-validate" class="form-validate-text"><p>
                <div id="floatContainer" class="float-container small active">
                    <label for="phoneNumber" class="floating-text">Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="tel" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" data-placeholder="Phone"><br>
                </div>
                <p id="phoneNumber-validate" class="form-validate-text"><p>
                <div id="floatContainer" class="float-container small">
                    <label for="problemDesc" class="floating-text">Description of problem</label>
                    <textarea id="problemDesc" name="problemDesc"></textarea><br>
                </div>
```

Comment: Most of your `.float-container` elements don't have any `textarea` in them (only the last one does), so `element.querySelector('textarea')` on those returns `null` and trying to read `.value` on that throws an error.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right, but how would I then have the script check/update the textarea's class when there's text inside of it?

Comment: Just add a guard: `const textArea = element.querySelector("textarea"); if (textArea) { /*...code to handle text area here...*/ }`.

Comment: It no longer throws the error, and the script doesn't crash however the textarea is still unresponsive unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather recommend giving your inputs and textareas a class like `input`.
This way you don't have to check, your field's type and it's current value.

```js
// add active class
const handleFocus = (e) => {
  const target = e.target;
  target.parentNode.classList.add("active");
  target.setAttribute("placeholder", target.getAttribute("data-placeholder"));
};

// remove active class
const handleBlur = (e) => {
  const target = e.target;
  if (!target.value) {
    target.parentNode.classList.remove("active");
  }
  target.removeAttribute("placeholder");
};


// register events
const bindEvents = (element) => {
  const floatField = element.querySelector(".input");
  if (floatField) {
    floatField.addEventListener("focus", handleFocus);
    floatField.addEventListener("blur", handleBlur);
  }
};

// get DOM elements
const init = () => {
  const floatContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".float-container");
  floatContainers.forEach((element) => {
    let input = element.querySelector(".input");
    let inputVal = input ? input.value : "";
    if (inputVal) {
      input.classList.add("active");
    }
    bindEvents(element);
  });
};


init();
```

```css
/*{
    width: 66%;
    position: relative;
}
*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}


.input{
  border: 2px dotted #000;
  width: 100%!important;
}

.float-container.small input
{
    width: 50%;
    outline-offset: 1px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 4px 10px 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.float-container.small textarea
{
    width: 100%;
    outline-offset: 1px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 4px 10px 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: red;
}

.float-container.large input 
{
    width: 100%;
    outline-offset: 1px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 4px 10px 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.float-container.active
{
    border: 2px solid #1A57FF;
    outline: 2px solid rgba(26, 87, 255, 0.3);
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.float-container.active label
{
    transform: translate(0, 4px) scale(.75);
}



.floating-text
{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
    transform: translate(0, 16px) scale(1);
    transform-origin: top left;
    transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="floatContainer" class="float-container small">
  <label for="fName" class="floating-text">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fName" class="input" name="fName" data-placeholder="First name"><br>
</div>
<p id="fName-validate" class="form-validate-text">
<p>
<div id="floatContainer" class="float-container small">
  <label for="lName" class="floating-text">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="lName" class="input" input name="lName" data-placeholder="Last name"><br>
</div>
<p id="lName-validate" class="form-validate-text">
<p>
<div id="floatContainer" class="float-container small">
  <label for="email" class="floating-text">Email</label>
  <input type="text"  class="input" id="email" name="email" data-placeholder="Email"><br>
</div>
<p id="email-validate" class="form-validate-text">
<p>
<div id="floatContainer" class="float-container small --active">
  <label for="phoneNumber" class="floating-text">Phone Number oi</label>
  <input type="tel" id="phoneNumber"  class="input" name="phoneNumber" data-placeholder="Phone"><br>
</div>
<p id="phoneNumber-validate" class="form-validate-text">
<p>
  
<div id="floatContainer" class="float-container small">
  <label for="problemDesc" class="floating-text">Description of problem</label>
  <textarea id="problemDesc" class="input" name="problemDesc"></textarea><br>
</div>
```

The init function might look like this (using a ternary operator to check the current value):

```
const init = () => {
  const floatContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".float-container");
  floatContainers.forEach((element) => {
    let input = element.querySelector(".input");
    let inputVal = input ? input.value : "";
    if (inputVal) {
      input.classList.add("active");
    }
    bindEvents(element);
  });
};
```

Comment: Hey, only stepped back to start working on this again. Yep, everything works & was a simple change. Not sure why I didn't consider this myself. Regardless, thank you. Selected as the answer.

Comment: @NorthernDev: thanks, but I also wondered, if you really need to change your display by js. You could also use `.float-container:focus-within label` to toggle your input styles via css – just an idea (don't get me wrong: I'm not a css-only-at-any-price-fan )

Comment: You raise a good point. I'm a fan of using as little JS as needs be personally. I'm not sure I was aware of the :focus-within pseudo class to be honest. I was under the impression I couldn't achieve this with just CSS. My front-end skills are still relatively weak, so I appreciate the CSS exclusive approach. I'll implement that now. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score -1):

For your commented code : you can use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to check for the existence of the querySelector('textarea') return object before accessing the value.

It looks like your bindEvents function is assigning the event listener to just input elements rather than input & textarea elements.

Edit: more info.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Doesn't passing element to bindEvents do that job? If I print the logs for element, I can see the text area there.